# Understanding why a point is problematic - improper integrals.

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I need to find for which $a,b$ The following integral converges.

$$
\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\frac{(\pi/2 - x)^ax^b}{\cos(x^2)^b}dx
$$

Now, my problem is that the answers say that the point $x=0$ Is problematic. I don’t understand why, the function is defined and bounded at $x=0$, what is the problem at that point?

Help please.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume they're talking about $a,b\lt0$.

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks

Comment: What happens when $ x = \sqrt{ \frac{\pi}{2} }$